# Unhide certain function with same name and different signature from base class in derived

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void f(int)
    {
        printf("Base f(int)\n");
    }

    virtual void f(int, int)
    {
        printf("Base f(int, int)\n");
    }
};

class Der : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::f;

    virtual void f(double)
    {
        printf("Der f(double)\n");
    }
};
```

So in this case I am able to use both functions from the base class. But is it possible to allow using in derived class only certain overloaded method from base? For example allow to use only f(int), but not f(int, int).

Comment: A class is not a namespace and the using directive is meant to be used for namespaces.

Comment: @izomorphius it's absolutely fine when bringing the names from base class to derived class

Comment: @izomorphius: No, the using directive is necessary in this situation. Otherwise, Der::f(double) would shadow Base::f(int).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to unhide base class methods with the `using` directive selectively. Unfortunately, it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 3):

This will do:

```
class Der : public Base {
...
  virtual void f(int p) { return Base::f(p); }
```

If performance is your concern, that will result in static dispatch to `void Base::f(int)`.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Mb i wasn't clear in my question - it is interesting to me is it possible to unhide certain base method with that "using" clause.

Comment: it's not possible to separate them, unless they are from separately named bases.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to hide only certain members from the base class by un-hiding all and then hiding again only specific ones (e.g. by providing a private override):

```
struct Base
{
    void f(int) {
        printf("Base f(int)\n");
    }

    void f(int, int) {
        printf("Base f(int, int)\n");
    }
};

struct Der : Base
{
    using Base::f; // unhide all f's from Base

    void f(double) {
        printf("Der f(double)\n");
    }

// hide f(int, int) from Base by declaring it as private (no implementation needed)
private:
    void f(int, int); 
};

void Example() {
    Der der;
    der.f(1); // OK Base::f(int)
    der.f(1.0f); // OK Der::f(double)
    der.f(1,1); // compiler error: 'f' is a private member of 'Der'
}
```